# Add multiple loading components with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

How can I add several loading components to nuxt and call it something like:

- for guest users
  `this.$nuxt.$loading.guestLoader.start()`
- for private users
  `this.$nuxt.$loading.privateLoader.start()`

docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/loading#using-a-custom-loading-component.

Any ideas?

Comment: @kissu. Hi! I made my own loading functionality using composition api instead of vuex

Comment: Pretty much the same no? How is it related to the loading bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
// useLoader.js
import { ref, computed } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

const state = ref({
  'app-guest-loader': false,
  'app-platform-loader': false
});

export function useLoader(context) {
  function start(loaderName) {
    state.value[loaderName] = true;
  }
  function stop(loaderName) {
    state.value[loaderName] = false;
  }

  const getOpenedLoaders = computed(() => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(state.value)) {
      if (value) { return key; }
    }
  });

  return {
    start,
    stop,
    getOpenedLoaders
  };
}
```

And a wrapper ***AppLoader.vue***

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <div v-if="getOpenedLoaders" class="app-loader">
      <component :is="getOpenedLoaders" />
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import AppGuestLoader from '@/components/appLoaders/AppGuestLoader';
import { useLoader } from '@/composition/useLoader';

export default {
  components: {
    AppGuestLoader
  },
  setup() {
    const { getOpenedLoaders, stop } = useLoader();

    setTimeout(() => {
      stop('app-guest-loader');
    }, 3000);

    return {
      getOpenedLoaders,
      stop
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  .app-loader {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
  }
  .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 2s
  }
  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a way of passing your own component to the loading component

```js
export default {
  loading: '~/components/LoadingBar.vue'
}
```

You could make the component's styles dynamic, let's say a red color for `guests` and a blue one for the `private` one and toggle between both by changing the vuex state.

To sum up:

- you have your component with some default red color
- you click on some auth or alike
- you make a vuex call to update the state saying that the user is authenticated
- let the component's style react to the vuex changes
- call the progress bar again
- see the updated progress bar style changed
- if he logs-out, the style will revert to red again

With something like this:

```html
<div :class="[store.isAuthenticated ? 'blue-color' : 'red-color']"></div>
```